# ASP.NET MVC issue with classes and results

Tags: asp.net

I have two classes, One is called Development, the other BuildingTypes...Development collects a list of BuildingTypes:

```
public class BuildingTypes
    {
        public string BuildingType { get; set; }
    }

    public class Development
    {
        public List<BuildingTypes> BuildingTypes { get; set; }

    }
```

what I am trying to is a list of BuildingType (no s) to get this result:

```
    <BuildingTypes>
    <BuildingType> Condo/Apartment </BuildingType>
    <BuildingType> Townhouse </BuildingType>
    </BuildingTypes>

But when I try this:

    List<BuildingTypes> buildingTypes = new List<BuildingTypes>();

                    if (houseCounter != 0)
                    {

                        BuildingTypes buildingType = new BuildingTypes();

                        buildingType.BuildingType = "House";

                        buildingTypes.Add(buildingType);

                    }

                    if (townsCounter != 0)
                    {

                        BuildingTypes buildingType = new BuildingTypes();

                        buildingType.BuildingType = "Townhouse";

                        buildingTypes.Add(buildingType);

                    }

                    development.BuildingTypes = buildingTypes;
```

I get this result:

```
<BuildingTypes>
<BuildingTypes>
<BuildingType>House</BuildingType>
</BuildingTypes>
<BuildingTypes>
<BuildingType>Townhouse</BuildingType>
</BuildingTypes>
</BuildingTypes>
```

Why do I get extra BuildingTypes Nodes? Sooooo weird.

Comment: What does this have to do with asp.net-mvc? And the output you have show looks like xml - how are you generating it?

Comment: The output is correct and no problem with it 
`Development.BuildingTypes[].BuildingType`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output follows your data model. If you would add the attributes, like in this example:

```
public class BuildingTypes
{
    [XmlElement("buildingType")]
    public string BuildingType { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("development")]
public class Development
{
    [XmlArray("collectionOfBuildingTypes")]
    [XmlArrayItem("buildingTypes")]
    public List<BuildingTypes> BuildingTypes { get; set; }
}
```

and check the output, it will brings light into your confusion.

```
<development>
    <collectionOfBuildingTypes>
        <buildingTypes>
            <buildingType>House</buildingType>
        </buildingTypes>
        <buildingTypes>
            <buildingType>Townhouse</buildingType>
        </buildingTypes>
    </collectionOfBuildingTypes>
</development>
```

To summarize, I think you want to have:

```
public class BuildingTypes
{
    [XmlElement("buildingType")]
    public string BuildingType { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("development")]
public class Development
{
    [XmlElement("buildingTypes")]
    public List<BuildingTypes> BuildingTypes { get; set; }
}
```